# How to remove the "-" from phone numbers and choose the phone numbers from a list of strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This may be easy, but I am new to python. Can anyone please help me out?

Here is the data:

```
data = {'contact': ['123-546-3454', 'Sarah', 'Cyrus', '2458703433', '789-862-4860', 'Juan']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
df

Out[1]:
    contact
0   123-546-3454
1   Sarah
2   Cyrus
3   2458703433
4   789-862-4860
5   Juan
```

I want to remove the '-' from the phone numbers and get two data frames by separating the phone numbers and the names.
The expected results:

```
Out[2]:
    contact
0   Sarah
1   Cyrus
2   Juan

Out[3]:
    contact
0   11235463454
1   2458703433
2   7898624860
```

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas series has `.str` which has function `.split()` to split the string and `.join()` to join a list. You can first split the contact using `.split('-')` and then join it using `.join('')`.

To get separate dataframes for contact and name, create a mask which is `True` for rows which are contact. `.str.contains(pattern)` is a function to check if regex `pattern` is present in string or not. For matching the contact, we can check if row only consists of digit or not, to match row with only digit, pattern is: `^[0-9]+$`.

After creating mask use `df[mask]` and `df[~mask]` to get the dataframes.

Use:

```
df['contact'] = df.contact.str.split("-").str.join('')
mask = df.contact.str.contains("^[0-9]+$")
df_contact = df[mask]
df_name = df[~mask]
```

Output:

```
>>> df_contact
      contact
0  1235463454
3  2458703433
4  7898624860


>>> df_name
  contact
1   Sarah
2   Cyrus
5    Juan
```

Answer (score 2):

try, using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) + [`str.isdigit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) to create a mask.

```
df['contact'] = df.contact.str.replace('-', '')

mask = df.contact.str.isdigit() # boolean mask

df[mask], df[~mask]
```

Comment: this won't remove hyphens from `df[mask]` though, only during the making of the mask

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of `replace()` method :

```
df['contact']=df['contact'].replace('-','',regex=True)
```

Finally create a boolean mask and use `isnumeric()` method and chain `reset_index()` method to it:

```
mask=df['contact'].str.isnumeric()

contactdf=df[mask].reset_index(drop=True)
namedf=df[~mask].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>>contactdf

    contact
0   1235463454
1   2458703433
2   7898624860

>>>namedf
    contact
0   Sarah
1   Cyrus
2   Juan
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `replace` then `to_numeric`

```
out1 = df.replace({'-':''},regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric,errors = 'coerce').dropna()
out2 = df.drop(out1.index)
out1
        contact
0  1.235463e+09
3  2.458703e+09
4  7.898625e+09
out2
  contact
1   Sarah
2   Cyrus
5    Juan
```